# How to make Enunciate show my data type as structured JSON (instead of as "custom")?

Tags: json, enunciate

I have this simple service which echoes an ID parameter wrapped in a JSON object:

```
@Path("job")
public class JobResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Job readById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        Job j = new Job();
        j.id = id;
        return j;
    }

}
```

The return value's `Job` class is declared as:

```
public class Job {
    public long id;
}
```

The documentation generated with Enunciate shows the service's data type as "custom". Is it possible to have Enunciate spit out a more detailed explanation of the return type, for example a JSON representation?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the return type to `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` the documentation should then show the data type as JSON.

You would need to slightly modify your method as:

```
...
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(j).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation to the Job class

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
```

Without this annotation the enunciate will display the DTO as "custom" or "file"

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem with a simple REST Jersey webservice.

Here are the annotations of My returned object (no more):

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "OReponseInitialiser")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
    @XmlType (name="OReponseInitialiser")
    public class OReponseInitialiser
```

And the webservice declaration:

```
      @POST
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Path ("initialiser")
      public OReponseInitialiser initialiser(@Context HttpServletRequest pRequete,  ...) throws OException
```

I build the documentation with the ant task

```
<enunciate 
    basedir="${projet.repertoire}/src"
    buildDir="${enunciate.working.dir}"
    javacSourceVersion="1.8"
    javacTargetVersion="1.8"
    configFile="${projet.repertoire}/build_enunciate.xml"
    >
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
  <export artifactId="docs" destination="${docs.dir}"/>
</enunciate>
```